# I generate excel sheet with sql query but it generates only in 93 version how can i make it to 2013 version?

Tags: sql-server, excel

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp " Select 'column' union all Select "
        cast(column  As nvarchar(max))from [NEWDATABASE].[dbo].[TempPower] WHERE BarCode = 'batman'"queryout D:\TempPower.xls -o "D:\querycommanddetails.txt" -T -c -C RAW'"
```

Answer (score 0):

`bcp` does not, from the documentation I can find, export to *any* Excel binary format. What you're doing is producing a delimited text file and giving it an Excel extension. But file extensions don't dictate how the data is stored/represented in the file; they're just a hint to tell Windows what application to open them in and the application a hint about how to process it.

If you open the file in a text editor, you'll see the raw data in plain text there. Excel may even give you a warning when you attempt to open a delimited text file that has the `xls` extension because it's not getting what it expected.

If you need to output directly to a `xslx` file, you'll need to produce it through another method.

Comment: thank you..Do u know other method which can be used to generate excel other than bcp?..i have tried other but seems to be difficult .

Comment: I think before you ask "how", you need to ask yourself why you need a binary Excel file instead of a delimited text file in the first place.